# QUERY for like-minded rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

**Scenario**

Consider the following query:

```
=QUERY(A15:E861, "select B, sum(D) group by B")
```

This works for rows with col B's that have the SAME description eg.

```
1 | abc | n | 10
2 | abc | n | 10
3 | cba | n | 10
```

Will result in

```
abc | 20
cba | 10
```

**Question**

But let's say I have

```
1 | abc-#ref123 some description    | n | 10
2 | abc-#ref456 another description | n | 10
3 | cba-#ref889 last description    | n | 10
```

And I want to ignore the "`$refxxx` description". How do I go about doing this?

Comment: regex it out before passing it to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### F1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(B15:B861; B15:B861; LEFT(B15:B861; 3)))
```

and then:

```
=QUERY(A15:H861; "select F, sum(D) group by F")
```

Comment: In practice the text I wanted was more in the middle so I used `MID` instead of `LEFT` but this definitely got me to my solution thanks.